# Using self join/inner join to get the data by adding all the above rows data, in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I am working with SQL server, the query details are as below:

Need to get the calculative column whose result will be the addition of all the above rows. And I can't use correlated queries, Lag and Lead as it is not supported.

I tried using self-join/inner join/left outer join, the only problem I am facing is due to group by clause of other columns the result is not coming as expected.

For example, data is like

[image: Data is like this image]

Expected Output

[image: Expected output is like this image]

But the output I am getting due to group by clause applied on Column4.
Output getting is like below [image]

Is there some alternative of `GROUP BY` clause or other alternatives?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Please, we need formatted text instead of images

Comment: do u have column 2 in incremental order ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The combination of a zero-effort question plus repeated begging that creates work for volunteer editors is not a good one. Please make an effort prior to asking any question here, and do not attempt to jump the queue.

Comment: Column 2 is not in incremented order

Comment: Can you please tag which version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: I tried with inner join/self join with group by clause on Column1, Column2, column4...

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you would simply use cumulative sum:

```
select d.*, sum(column3) over (order by column2)
from data d;
```

Answer (score 0):

using subquery for earlier version of 2012

```
SELECT  Column1,Column2,Column3,
        ( SELECT    SUM(y.Column3)
          FROM      Data y
          WHERE     y.Column1 = x.Column1
                    AND y.Column2 <= x.Column2
        ) AS [Column5(Summation of Column3)]
FROM    Data x
ORDER BY 1 ,2 ,3;
```

Query result

[image]

Comment: I don't see why you need to order by 1, 2, 3?

Comment: @sami  order the results by col1 then col2 then col3. If you need just order by 2nd column then you just write order by 2

Comment: @NupurLamha  which version of sql server you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved!!

**Earlier my query was like,
SELECT a.*,
CASE WHEN col4!= A THEN SUM col3 ELSE 0 END
FROM a
GROUP BY col4, *...**

This groupby was causing issue as it was giving the expected output

**The things I changes in the query is,
SELECT a.*,
SUM(CASE WHEN col4!= A THEN col3 ELSE 0 END)
FROM a
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN col4!= A THEN col3 ELSE 0 END)**

Now it is giving result as expected.

Thank you everyone for the help!!